# Maximize $ | x^\top A x | $ and $x$ is a unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

$ A $ is  a square matrix and $x$ is a unit vector. We want to maximize  $ | x^\top A x | $ for $x$. The solutions I saw so far are based on calculus and Lagrange Multipliers. Is it possible to solve this problem with linear algebra arguments ? I can definitely do that if $A$ is symmetric, in this case I can represent $x$ as a linear combination of an orgthonormal eigenvectors of $A$ and the rest is easy. I wonder how to solve this problem with linear algebra for any square matrix $A$.

Comment: Notice that $x^{T}Ax=\left(x^{T}Ax\right)^{T}=x^{T}A^{T}x$ so you can have a symmetric matrix $B=\frac{1}{2}\left(A+A^{T}\right)$ and evaluate $x^{T}Bx$ instead

Comment: This concerns the maximum of the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient).

Comment: Using the same link as hardmath's, the maximum of the Rayleigh quotient is known as the spectral radius and coincides with the magnitude of the largest eigenvalue. So the problem amounts to showing, with linear algebra alone, $|x^\top A x|\leq \lambda_{max}$ with equality iff $x$ is the corresponding eigenvector. (I suggest looking up Jordan normal form to cover the non-symmetric case.)